# encrypt a string using Des64 and Des192 encryption algorithm in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, security, ios, encryption, cryptography

I want to **encrypt a string** using **des64** and **des192** in **iPhone** . 
           I have searched the internet and found some code but the thing is I am not that aware of cryptography . I heard that in iPhone we can make use of security framework which has got cryptography functions. But they are totally c based and really hard to understand .

Can anybody please direct me to some helpful resource or explain the code which is used to encrypt in iPhone ???

Thanks in advance !!

Bharat

Comment: There is no DES mode which takes 64bit or 192bit keys. DES (and 3DES) always has a block size of 64bits. I have no clue what you mean by DES64 or DES192.

Comment: @Yann - Yes actualy DES is Des64 and and 3DES is Des192 ( as 3 DES takes 3 * 64 = 192 bits ).

Comment: @Bharat, you can call 3DES as DES192, but I dont think people will be impressed by invented nomenclatures.

Comment: @Vineet: Yes may be . .  But My concern was a not about that .

Comment: Can any body please help with the question I have posted here ?? Please !!!!

Comment: No, single DES has a 56bit key, 3DES has 168bit key. There is no such thing as DES192. (192bit AES exists)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Crypto isn't usually simple. The [iPhone Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html) has an example project including some symmetric crypto using Objective-C.

Essentially though, you follow these kinds of steps (not specific to any particular crypto API).

```
init_crypto_library();

key k = crypto_load_key("my/key.dat");
cipher c = crypto_init_cipher(k, CBCMODE);

while ( char* buf == get_plaintext() ){
  crypto_encrypt( c, buf );
}
char* encrypted = crypto_finalize_cipher( c );
crypto_unload_key( k );
```

You should always try to consider how safe the secret key is in your system. You can't really trust keeping it safe forever.